# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler

Tags: spring

i am creteing maven project and i got some error which im amntn below

Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler

```
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext: Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
        Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `spring-security-config` dependency into your `pom.xml`, you can find it below. and you can also refer `4.2.3.RELEASE` but you need to use only version which match your other spring version, you can find it form below link:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```